# Input and Floating Strings errors

Tags: python, string, floating-point, integer

*I'm trying to construct a Price calculator on Python and I'm receiving the following error:* `TypeError: 'str' object is not callable`
**On this line of my code:**

```
tax_rate = float(input("What is the sales tax rate? "))
```

**The complete code is this one:**

```
print("Please enter the following information:")
print()
child_meal = float(input("What is the price of a child's meal? "))
adult_meal = float(input("What is the price of an adult's meal? "))
child_number = input=("What is the number of childrens? ")
adult_number = input=("What is the number of adults? ")
tax_rate = float(input("What is the sales tax rate? "))

total_child_meal = int(child_meal) * int(child_number)
total_adult_meal = int(adult_meal) * int(adult_number)
sub_total = int(total_child_meal) + int(total_adult_meal)
sales_tax = float(sub_total) * float(tax_rate) / 100
total_amount = float(sub_total) + float(sales_tax)
print()
print(f"What's the price of a child's meal? {child_meal}")
print(f"What's the price of an adult's meal? {adult_meal}")
print(f"How many children are there? {child_number}")
print(f"How many adults are there? {adult_number}")
print(f"What is the sales tax rate? {tax_rate}")
print()
print(f"Subtotal: {sub_total}")
print(f"Sales Tax: {sales_tax}")
print(f"Total: {total_amount}")
print()
payment_amount = float(input("What is the payment amount? "))
change = float(payment_amount) - float(total_amount)
print(f"Change: {change}")
```

I'm not sure why the line for tax_rate string is failing since is the same example for float string I used in child_meal string.

Can you help me to identify the error here? I truly appreciate!

Comment: What are you entering into the `input`?

Comment: Typo.  Can you see in the 5th and 6th line that you have written `input=(` instead of `input(`?  That's the cause.  Voting to close as typo.  Did you not notice that it never asked you for the number of children or adults?

Comment: Hey @FreddyMcloughlan thanks for the quick reply!
Well, The input is 4.50 for child_meal string and 9.00 for adult_meal

Comment: @TimRoberts I noticed that! Trying to remove the = on the lines and is now asking!! Simple error huh? Grateful!!

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

On the 5ht and 6th lines of your code, you have a bit of a mess up here. Which is fine!

**What You Have**

```
child_number = input=("What is the number of childrens? ")
adult_number = input=("What is the number of adults? ")
```

**What You Want**

What you want is to get rid of the "=" between the input and the parameters.

```
child_number = input("What is the number of childrens? ")
adult_number = input("What is the number of adults? ")
```

After that, the code works great! Nice work.

Answer (score 1):

if you want to get input from user:

```
child_number = input("What is the number of childrens? ")
adult_number = input("What is the number of adults? ")
```